Enable KIOSK mode. Define my custom app the only one to be executed on my device
I developed an Android application using Android Studio. I purchased a DOOGEE R10 tablet, and what I want to do is make my app the only one displayed on my tablet. I enabled Kiosk mode using this code:
        if (devicePolicyManager.isAdminActive(adminComponent)) {
            startLockTask();
        }

However, it is possible to exit Kiosk mode by tapping two default navigation buttons on Android. I want to disable this behavior to prevent the tablet from displaying other pages or applications. My application must be the only one running on my tablet.
I hope you can help me, and I thank you in advance.
